# How do I change the working directory while running Jetty with Maven?

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm running a Jetty server using Maven by executing the `mvn jetty:run` goal. In my Java code, I read files using `java.io.File`, but my existing code assumes that the process is running in the `/war` directory under my `basedir`.

How do I set the working directory when using the Maven Jetty plugin?

Details:
Those files are not directly under the `baseDirectory` but under a child directory: specifically, the `webapp`  directory, which is copied to the target folder under `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}`

I want to read the files without having to add the target path every time I define a file.

I can read files using.

```
File file = new File("target/myProject-myVersion/fileToRead.txt")
```

I just want to do:

```
File file = new File("fileToRead.txt")
```

Below is the project structure. (It's the typical Maven webapp structure.)

```
MyDir/
  [pom.xml]
  src/main/
    java/
      com.example.mycode/
        MyCode.java
    webapp/
      [fileToRead.txt]
      [index.html]
      [jsp.jsp]
      WEB-INF/
        [web.xml]
```

In `pom.xml` I have:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ServletContext.getRealPath(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-) API.

```java
File file = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/fileToRead.txt"));
```